# SELECT COLUMN_NAMES is VALUE in Other TABLE (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

tbl 1

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|   ID   |  th  | room |  A   |  B   |  C  |
+--------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      1 |  10  |    1 |   50 |   60 |  70 |
|      2 |  20  |    1 |  100 |  120 | 140 |
|      3 |  30  |    2 |  150 |  180 | 210 |
|      4 |  40  |    2 |  200 |  240 | 280 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

tbl 2

```
+--------+------+------+
|   ID   | rom  | CLM  |
+--------+------+------+
|      1 |   1  |   A  |
|      2 |   1  |   B  |
|      3 |   2  |   A  |
|      4 |   3  |   A  |
|      5 |   3  |   B  |
|      6 |   4  |   C  |
+--------+------+------+
```

- if tbl_2.rom = 1 **tbl_2.clm = A**, then I want to select COLUMN **"A"** from tbl_1
- if tbl_2.rom = 1 **tbl_2.clm = B**, then I want to select COLUMN **"B"** from tbl_1
- if tbl_2.rom = 4 **tbl_2.clm = C**, then I want to select COLUMN **"C"** from tbl_1

How to do it in query ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a problem of poor design

Comment: thnks, its the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.room, CASE WHEN b.clm='A' THEN a.A WHEN b.clm='B' THEN a.B ELSE a.C END 
FROM tbl_1 a INNER JOIN tbl_2 b ON a.room=b.room
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
select tbl_1.*, tbl_2.CLM from tbl_1,tbl_2 where tbl_1.room=tbl_2.room
```

Comment: thnks, but its still give me col | A | B | C |, i only need one col_name by value of tbl_2